# Running sequential Futures with similar shapes using for comprehension

Tags: scala, scalaz

```
def func1(list : List[T]) : Future[\/[Throwable,Unit] ]
def func2(list : List[T]) : Future[List[\/[Throwable,Unit]]]
```

where `T` is just a specific type and that type will be same for both the functions. Now func2 is dependent on success of first `func` 's future. so `func2` should run sequentially only after `func` completed successfully. I want a `for` comprehension something in a similar line as below (following isn't valid compilable code) and return `Future[\/[Throwable,Unit] ]`

```
def func3 combiner(list) : Future[\/[Throwable,Unit] ] = for{
  u <- func1(list)
  us <- u
  d <- func2(list)
}yield
```

Any pointers how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Because futures either complete with a value or an exception you won't need the Either (or do you have other reasons for using it?).
Running this code should help you (and reading the [documentation on futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f1(l: List[Int]): Future[Int] = future { println("f1"); l head }
def f2(l: List[Int]): Future[Int] = future { println("f2"); throw new Exception("bang") }
def f3(l: List[Int]): Future[Int] = future { println("f3"); l last }

val result1 = for {
  x1 <- f2(List(1, 2))
  x2 <- f1(List(1, 2)) // f1 is not run
} yield x2

val result2 = for {
  x1 <- f1(List(1, 2))
  x3 <- f3(List(1, 2))
} yield x3

result1.onComplete(res => println("result1 = " + res))
result2.onComplete(res => println("result2 = " + res))
```